# Using a stored procedure within Domain Service in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I created a Domain Service and a stored procedure within, I followed all steps but the stored procedure can't be found in the client Side. My tables names are pochrhts and poordedts, and the stored procedure name is bel_web_Supplier_ConfirmedPOs and it uses two parameter. Can you please help me with this please ?

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class DomainService1 : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<Web_DatabaseEntities>
{

    // TODO:
    // Consider constraining the results of your query method.  If you need additional input you can
    // add parameters to this method or create additional query methods with different names.
    // To support paging you will need to add ordering to the 'pochrhts' query.
    public IQueryable<pochrht> GetPochrhts()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.pochrhts;
    }

    // TODO:
    // Consider constraining the results of your query method.  If you need additional input you can
    // add parameters to this method or create additional query methods with different names.
    // To support paging you will need to add ordering to the 'poordedts' query.
    public IQueryable<poordedt> GetPoordedts()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.poordedts;
    }

    // TODO:
    // Consider constraining the results of your query method.  If you need additional input you can
    // add parameters to this method or create additional query methods with different names.
    // To support paging you will need to add ordering to the 'poordehts' query.
    public IQueryable<poordeht> GetPoordehts()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.poordehts;
    }


    public IQueryable<bel_web_Supplier_ConfirmedPOs_Result> bel_web_Supplier_ConfirmedPOs(string a, int b) 
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.bel_web_Supplier_ConfirmedPOs(a, b).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your stored procedure's signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to expose an IQueryable from within a method with no parameters (just return null) and see if something change. As far as I remember wcf ria needs that all entities must be exposed with a "default" (no parameters) method

HTH